Accessing Network Shares on a Windows machine that doesn't require a password
I can access Network Shares on a Windows machine with password-protected file sharing easily (thank God that's easy to set up), but if accessing another Windows computer that is without password protection, Ubuntu asks for credentials and anything I try gives "invalid arguments" (whether I leave stuff blank or try to use the Windows Guest account). The corresponding Windows machine's Event Viewer shows "Audit Success" for the logon attempt, so the issue is definitely on Ubuntu's side, I suspect. I can access that Windows computer's shared folders from any other device I have, and without any trouble, the computer running Ubuntu is the only exception.
I've also tried "sudo mount -t cifs //<ip_and_path> /mnt/ -o sec=ntlm" and then get prompted for a password when there is none required for that Windows computer that has password-less file sharing enabled. (got that from How to connect to Windows Share Without Password without modifying Windows?)
I don't know what credentials to try or configurations to change to access the shared folder.
I tried editing smb.conf if it might help. I only edited the "workgroup" parameter to match my Windows machines. Other system configurations that require digging through etc or using Terminal commands should be untouched.
Ubuntu 22.04LTS (Xorg/Gnome), Windows machines all run Windows 10. cifs-utils, smbclient, and winbind are all apt-installed. I did install ubuntustudio-installer last week to check out the software and get the low-latency kernel of Ubuntu Studio (in case that somehow affects all this, though i doubt it). All computers are on the same local network and connected via Wifi. I also do not have any issues accessing my shared folder on my Ubuntu machine from any of my Windows machines, so that much is working quite well.

You mention adding the low-latency kernel (which can be added without using the Ubuntu Studio installer too) which disables some features, so are you using that kernel? or the generic kernel?  As per Ubuntu Studio docs, you use the low latency kernel when producing professional grade audio, and are recommended to use generic for normal usage.


I've also tried "sudo mount -t cifs //<ip_and_path> /mnt/ -o sec=ntlm"
and then get prompted for a password when there is none required for
that Windows computer that has password-less file sharing enabled.
(got that from How to connect to Windows Share Without Password
without modifying Windows?) I don't know what credentials to try or
configurations to change to access the shared folder.

There is no "sec=ntlm" in the version of mount.cifs you are using in Ubuntu 22.04.
Since the server is Win10 it's not needed anyway.
If you are trying to access as a guest user pass the "guest" option in your cifs statement.
Give this a shot:
sudo mount -t cifs //<ip_and_path> /mnt/ -o guest,uid=1000

Note: It's not ip and path. it's ip and share-name
Note: I added a uid=1000 so that if you make the mount you can actually write to it. It assumes your id number on the Linux machine is 1000. Run id to verify
